# Importing Excel .csv to SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am importing Excel files and csvs to SQLite and the dates are being imported as the Excel float format (41323.11). Can I dictate that they should be imported in a certain format which can easily be viewed when I query? (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

My problem is that I export this data into csv and manipulate it with pandas. I seem to have a lot of trouble getting pandas to recognize that these are really dates.. I have to open the files, reformat the data columns, save, open the file with notepad and save as UTF-8, just to get the date functions to work in pandas.

Comment: Isn't this question about how to get Excel to export in the correct CSV format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try "parse_dates" when importing your CSV?
like this:

`In [53]: df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
            A  B  C
date

2009-01-01  a  1  2
2009-01-02  b  3  4
2009-01-03  c  4  5`